# Combining pictures with C++ and OpenCV

Tags: c++, opencv

I'm trying to use C++ and OpenCV to combine pictures, but an error occurs.

My code:

[image: my code]

The error:

> Assertion failed (size.width>0 && size.height>0) in imshow

[image: the error]

Comment: Paste code and error in question as text. Not screenshot.

Comment: Also, are you sure the logo image is there? You've asked for an image named `dota_log.png`. Should it be `dota_logo.png`?

Comment: this error commonly occurs when the input image you've specified is not accessible. Check that the Mat you're passing to imshow is not null

Comment: add a `if(logo.empty()) doSomethingLikePrintingErrorButDon'tTryToUseTheImage`. Check the path of your logo file, check that the file isn't broken, etc.

Answer (score 0):

What is the `199` in `imread(..., 199)` supposed to mean?

[Valid values are](http://docs.opencv.org/master/d4/da8/group__imgcodecs.html#ga61d9b0126a3e57d9277ac48327799c80):

> - **IMREAD_UNCHANGED** If set, return the loaded image as is (with alpha channel, otherwise it gets cropped).
> - **IMREAD_GRAYSCALE** If set, always convert image to the single channel grayscale image.
> - **IMREAD_COLOR** If set, always convert image to the 3 channel BGR color image.
> - **IMREAD_ANYDEPTH** If set, return 16-bit/32-bit image when the input has the corresponding depth, otherwise convert it to 8-bit.
> - **IMREAD_ANYCOLOR** If set, the image is read in any possible color format.
> - **IMREAD_LOAD_GDAL** If set, use the gdal driver for loading the image.
> - a few other options for reduced grayscale images.

Usually you want to load the image in BGR:

```
Mat img = imread("/path/to/img.png"); // IMREAD_COLOR is default value
```

or in grayscale

```
Mat img = imread("/path/to/img.png", IMREAD_GRAYSCALE);
```